# Updating Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed to ver 1.1.0 breaks Template10 also Template don't pass windows store cert

Tags: template10

after updating  `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` to version `1.1.0` 
Template10 app doesn't build with error:

```
 CS0012 
The type 'ActionCollection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
You must add a reference assembly.
```

Also all Apps built with template10 including blank/hamburger/minimal templates (latest Template10 version 1.1.5) without any code added fail Windows app certification kit App prelaunch test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/700 - Jerry thinks that something is wrong with 1.1.0, so use 1.0.3 for now.

Answer (score 2):

It broke for all of us, we pulled it out. Get latest, please.